# how to get the application running time - iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to calculate the running time of application that is when the application was started and then when it was closed.

Starting can be logged in application did finish launching but application will terminate is not working for me as when home button is pressed the application fires event "applicationWillResignActive" but user may start the application again or user can quit the application. When I try to quit the application application will terminate event is not occurring.

How can I then find out the application running time ?

Many Thanks,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 0):

If you're on iOS 4, you probably want `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear. Question was "How can I then find out the application running time ?".